# What does (char **)(&samples) declare?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Given: `SInt16 *samples = NULL;`

What does `(char **)(&samples)` declare?

Edit to show actual use case:

```
CMBlockBufferGetDataPointer(audioBlockBuffer, audioBlockBufferOffset, &lengthAtOffset, &totalLength, (char **)(&samples));
//  CMBlockBufferGetDataPointer(<CMBlockBufferRef theBuffer>, <size_t offset>, <size_t *lengthAtOffset>, <size_t *totalLength>, <char **dataPointer>)
```

Comment: Ah, I see now. But in this case, wouldn't `char *samples = NULL` then be the right declaration for your pointer to match the CMBlockBufferGetDataPointer definition? then you don't need to use the (char **) cast. Personally, if I can get rid of casts, I feel more confident that I won't accidentally reference the data incorrectly.

Comment: @Robert Ryan: That came out of Apple's SpeakHere sample app.  I was just trying to figure how to get to the buffer data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** The original question was asking simply `What does (char **)(&samples) declare?` As such, in my original answer I tried to outline the possible uses of that syntax in the abstract. But subsequently it was clarified that this was for a parameter to `CMBlockBufferGetDataPointer`. But I'll leave my original answer for the sake of completeness.

**Original answer:**

This syntax has one of two possible interpretations. First, this syntax can be used as a pointer to a pointer of a `SInt16` which has been cast to a pointer to a pointer of a `char`. By the way, Apple uses the term *indirect reference* for these pointers to pointers. Or, second, this could be a pointer to an array of `SInt16` which has been cast to a pointer to an array of `char`. It depends upon how this `(char **)&samples` is being used.

Focusing on the first interpretation, in your example the variable `samples` is defined to be `(SInt16 *)`, a pointer (or *direct reference*) to a `SInt16` (a signed short integer). Thus `&samples` is the address of that that `samples` pointer, which could properly be used in any situation where you need to pass a pointer to a pointer (an indirect reference) of a `SInt16`, namely `(SInt16 **)`.

In terms of where you'd use a pointer to a pointer, an indirect reference, it's frequently used when you have a method that will allocate some memory for some object and it needs to update one of your pointers with a reference to this new object. The most common Cocoa example of this construct is the frequent use of `(NSError **)`. You can see examples of this in Apple's [Error Handling Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-BAJIIGCC).

What's strange about your example, is that you're casting `&samples`, your indirect reference to a `SInt16` (or a pointer to an array of `SInt16`), to be a `(char **)`, a `char` indirect reference (or an array of `char`). That sends a shudder down the spine of all of us reformed C programmers. If you do this, you should be very, very comfortable with the code that is using this construct as this is a little dangerous. But I realize that we're sometimes constrained by legacy code.

Comment: See my comment for dasblinkenlight.

Comment: Robert Ryan: Your answer is >> 25 points!!!!.  I will have to reread again and again.  But I now have a much better picture… I believe in my case it was "a pointer to an array of SInt16 which has been cast to a pointer to an array of char".   I updated my original question with the actual syntax in use.   If you could make a comment on it.  I really am appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It interprets the array of what I assume to be 16 bit shorts as an array of pointers to `char`s. That means that if the shorts provided aren't valid pointers, you're in deep trouble.

Comment: See my comment for dasblinkenlight.

Answer (score 3):

Given that variables are declared only once, the `(char **)(&samples)` is a pointer *expression*, not a *declaration*. It casts an `SInt16` pointer to `char**`.

Comment: I have a dilemma:  Each of answers from dasblinkenlight, Linuxios, and Robert Ryan has the explanation that I was looking for.  But neither one is complete by itself from my respective.  So, I will upvote each answer for now…